# Find value using EXIST keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the next table: `code, year, day`

I want to find the code of the courses that was taken in 2000 in Sunday **and** Monday.

So I wrote the next query:

```
Select DISTINCT dbo.Course.Code
From dbo.Course
Where dbo.Course.CourseYear = 2000 AND 
EXISTS (Select * From dbo.course Where (dbo.course.day = 'Sunday' and dbo.Course.CourseYear = 2000))and 
EXISTS (Select * From dbo.course Where (dbo.course.day = 'Monday' and dbo.Course.CourseYear = 2000))
```

It's return me the courses that were given in 2000, in Sunday **or** Monday. Why?

Comment: Following on from Lucero's answer you should read this article about `join` vs `in` vs `exists`: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enforce that the **same** course record is being checked in both exists statement.
Your exists statement only ensure that there exists any course that was offered in sunday and any course that was offered on monday

Revising your query:

```
Select DISTINCT dbo.Course.Code
From dbo.Course c
Where dbo.Course.CourseYear = 2000 AND 
EXISTS (Select * From dbo.course Where (dbo.course.day = 'Sunday' and dbo.Course.CourseYear = 2000 and dbo.course.Code = c.Code))and 
EXISTS (Select * From dbo.course Where (dbo.course.day = 'Monday' and dbo.Course.CourseYear = 2000 and dbo.course.Code = c.Code))
```

A better written version

```
select distinct c.code
from
dbo.course c
inner join dbo.course c2 on c.code = c2.code
where
c.CourseYear = 2000
and c2.CourseYear = 2000
and c.Day = 'Monday'
and c2.Day = 'Sunday'
```

Also note that your schema is not normalized. You should have two tables:

1. Course (CourseId, Code)
2. CourseInstance (CourseId, Day, Year)

Answer (score 2):

Is this homework?

The query doesn't work as expected because your query only requires that *any* course in the year 2000 was on Mondays or Sundays - but it isn't specific to the row you're looking at.

```
SELECT c1.Code
FROM dbo.Course AS c1
WHERE c1.CourseYear = 2000 
AND c1.day = 'Sunday' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Course AS c2 
    WHERE (c1.Code = c2.Code) AND (c2.day = 'Monday'))
```

Comment: @Milimetric, he writes: "I want to find the code of the courses that was taken in 2000 in Sunday **and** Monday." - which I still understand as being what I coded.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually not what it's giving you.  The way you're using exists, you're asking the server to return each record if ANY records exist in the table that satisfy "Sunday" and 2000, AND if any records exist that satisfy "Monday" and 2000.  So the one way to query and get what you're trying to ask is:

```
 select c.Code
   from dbo.Course c
  where c.CourseYear = 2000
  group by
        c.Code
 having sum(case when c.day = 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    and sum(case when c.day = 'Monday' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```